# MongoDB import error assertion 9998

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I seem to keep having this error when i try and import anything?

In terminal I input:

```
name:~ computer$ mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --file /Users/computer/Desktop/ftse100.csv
connected to: 127.0.0.1
assertion: 9998 you need to specify fields
```

I wouldn't know what to ask. I tried adding --field after this command line but just get help information.

ER

Comment: maybe is typo, you need to use --fields not --field http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

Comment: There can be something more going one than just missing fields. Using 2.4.6, for example, I get this error eveen though I had a header line... if I copy the same line of text and place after -f option, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per mongodb [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

```
 --fields <field1[,field2]>, -f
```

Specify a comma separated list of field names when importing csv or tsv files that do not have field names in the first (i.e. header) line of the file.

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --file /Users/computer/Desktop/ftse100.csv --fields field1, field2,field3
```

As per your question, there is a typo it's not `--field` instead `--fields`

Answer (score 0):

In 2.4.6, mongoimport does not find the header in csv files that I make, with or without double quote boundaries.

If I chop off the header line and supply that same text to the -f or --fields option, it my files import fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all columns, use `--headerline` option instead of `-fields`.

In your case it would be:

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --headerline --file /Users/computer/Desktop/ftse100.csv
```